# Indexing logs in Logstash using application ports

Tags: java, spring, logging, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm using ELK Stack, this dependency and config in order to log my APIs.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.piomin</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-logging-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

And in properties:

```
logging.logstash.enabled: true
logging.logstash.url: 127.0.0.1:5000
logging.logstash.ignorePatterns: /(actuator|swagger|webjars).*
logging.logstash.logHeaders: true
```

I have several applications using different ports like ==> application A: localhost:9000, Application B: localhost:9001, ...
All the logs are sent to Logstash with the following config:

```
input {
   tcp {
    port => 5000
    codec => json
    type => "AppA"
  }
   tcp {
    port => 5000
    codec => json
    type => "AppB"

  }
}

filter {
       if [type] == "AppA" {
            mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][target_index]" => "AppA" } }
      } else if [type] == "AppB" {
            mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][target_index]" => "AppB" } }
      }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
             hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
             index => "%{[@metadata][target_index]}"
                  }
}
```

But it does not work. I want to index them according to ports or names of applications. any solution?

Comment: Logstash won't start with this configuration, you can't use the same port twice. Are you using the same port twice or this is just an example? What do you have in logstash logs?

Comment: I wanted to express my goal. This dependency will log all API calls. But I have 2 different applications sending logs to port 5000 (Logstash). after the sending I need to index the logs separately. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to filter your events and send to different index based on the input they came, you just need to use conditionals in the output block, the same way you did in the filters block.

You need something like the following pipeline.

```
input {
    tpc {
        port => 5000
        type => "AppA"
    }
    tpc {
        port => 6000
        type => "AppB"
    }
}

filter {
    if [type] == "AppA" {
        filters for type AppA
    } else if [type] == "AppB" {
        filters for type AppB
    }
}

output {
    if [type] == "AppA" {
        elasticsearch {
            index for AppA
        }
    } else if [type] == "AppB" {
        elasticsearch {
            index for AppB
        }
    }
}
```